# Detect each 4 using modulus php

Tags: php, wordpress, count, modulus

I am trying to detect each 4th post to insert extra code in my layout in wordpress using modulus method but I just cant get it.

Here is a short example of mine:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $count=0;?>   
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="column">

<!--content-->

</div> 

    <?php
            if ($count % 4 == 0){     
                echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
            }      
            $count++;       
            ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

all that is inside the while loop. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: And how does generated html look like?

Comment: Your code isn't inside a `while()` loop. Please give more information; what HTML is output by your current code?

Comment: updated the code. Just wanted to show modulus part.

Comment: I must appologise as I did not make it clear, I intent to detect each 4th post to insert a clear.

Comment: `if ($count % 4 == 0){` doesnt work?

Comment: What exactly is not working, what does the html look like?

Comment: @Nemoden $count % 4 == 0 detects the first post and places my clear div code right after that. I need a 4th

Comment: @jeroen my modulus $count % 4 == 0 detects the first post although it should be 4th

Comment: You might want to edit that into the question, as it makes it a lot clearer :-)

Comment: so, just add a condition for first loop `$count!=0 && $count%4==0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to start your counter at 1, as you are increasing it at the end of the loop:

```
<?php $count=1;?>
```

Either that, or you increase it at the start of the loop / before the check:

```
<?php
        $count++; 
        if ($count % 4 == 0){     
            echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
        }            
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

When it comes to things like this, I always increment one on the if statement before calling modulo like so:

`if(($count+1)%4 == 0)`

This way it's easy for me to make a mental note that the statement naturally reads "if the current count is the 4th one then do:"