# How to loop $num in php, e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4,

Tags: php, arrays, loops, integer

I am applying classes to elements on my page using $num in PHP.

So I have:

```
<?php $num = 0; ?>

<div class="<?php print ++$num; ?>"></div>
```

I have 16 divs, but I don't want the classes to go all the way to 16. I want them to go up to 4 and then back down to 1. So I want the classes as:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

rather than

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16
```

Can anyone give me some insight?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect each 4 using modulus php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780012/detect-each-4-using-modulus-php)

Comment: Did you know that (++$num%4)+1 will print only numbers 1 through 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve it.

```
<div class="<?php echo ($num++ % 4) + 1; ?>"></div>
```

**(edited)**

Pure PHP code. Use this logic to fix your need.

```
<?php 
$num = 0; 
while($num < 16){
    echo ($num++ % 4) + 1; 
}
?>
```

This gives

`1234123412341234`

Comment: Won't that print 0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3, not what he asked for: 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4 ?

Comment: @kainaw is right... this prints 0's. Is there a way to start new loops at 1? thanks for the code though...halfway tehre!

Comment: @caustic Did you completely ignore my comment above? If you have a 0 and you want a 1, just use `+1`. It magically adds one to it.

Comment: @kainaw - Sorry I missed your comment! Anyway, I just tried it, and yes it does add 1, but there is another problem. the first number prints as 2 instead of 1, but the loops after print with number 1 first. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You dont need to initialize it as `-1`, keep it as `0`. But all you have to do is change `++$num` to `$num++`

Answer (score 1):

I guess, something like this:

```
<?php
$num = 0;
while($num<4) {
$num++;
   echo "<div class='".$num."'></div>";
   if ($num==4) {
   $num=0;
}
}

?>
```