# Assigning a DIV in while loop

Tags: php, sql

Hello guys and thanks in advance. So I have a while loop that looks like this:

```
<?php
    $limit = 4;
    $countSql = "SELECT COUNT(book_id) FROM books";
    $tot_result = mysqli_query($conn, $countSql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($tot_result);
    $total_records = $row[0];
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);
    if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };
    $start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY book_id DESC LIMIT $start_from, $limit";
    $rs_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) {
        $book_titlel=$row['book_titlel'];
        $book_titlel=sanitize($book_titlel);
        echo "<div class='grid_2 col-md_4'><div class='box_9'><div class='img-wrap'><a href='book/".$book_titlel."/".$row['book_id']."'><img alt='".$row['book_title']."' data-src='images/books/".$row['book_picture'].".jpg' src='images/preloader.gif'></a></div><div class='caption'><div class='rating-bar'><div class='rating' style='width: 50%'></div></div><h3 class='text_5 color_1'><a href='book/".$book_titlel."/".$row['book_id']."'>".$row['book_title']."</a></h3><p class='text_6 color_3'><a href='book/".$book_titlel."/".$row['book_id']."'>".$row['book_author']."</a></p></div></div></div>";
    };
?>
```

So what I am trying to do is to assign a DIV every 4 results; for example:
results from 1 to 4 to be wrapped in        `<div class='row'></div>` , from 5 to 8 in a new `<div class='row'></div>`, from 9 to 12 too and so on. Is it possible?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780012/detect-each-4-using-modulus-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In front of your loop I put opened div your wrapper and then in every 4th entering in loop it will close div and open a new one

```
<?php 
$limit = 4;
$countSql = "SELECT COUNT(book_id) FROM books";
$tot_result = mysqli_query($conn, $countSql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($tot_result);
$total_records = $row[0];
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };
    $start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY book_id DESC LIMIT $start_from, $limit";
    $rs_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $i = 0;
    echo '<div id="yourwrapper">';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) {
        if($i %4 == 0){echo '</div><div id="yourwrapper">';}
        $book_titlel=$row['book_titlel'];
        $book_titlel=sanitize($book_titlel);
        echo "<div class='grid_2 col-md_4'><div class='box_9'><div class='img-wrap'><a href='book/".$book_titlel."/".$row['book_id']."'><img alt='".$row['book_title']."' data-src='images/books/".$row['book_picture'].".jpg' src='images/preloader.gif'></a></div><div class='caption'><div class='rating-bar'><div class='rating' style='width: 50%'></div></div><h3 class='text_5 color_1'><a href='book/".$book_titlel."/".$row['book_id']."'>".$row['book_title']."</a></h3><p class='text_6 color_3'><a href='book/".$book_titlel."/".$row['book_id']."'>".$row['book_author']."</a></p></div></div></div>";
        $i++;
    };
echo '</div>';

?>
```

Comment: What does $opened stand for? I think it is not defined

Comment: I think i removed it? It was just an idea while I was answering your code and I edited to remove it. @TsvetilinBoynovski

Comment: @TsvetilinBoynovski I edited again code and put $i++ lower in the loop because in original there was a posibility that first run will do only 3 element in div and now it should work. Does it?

Comment: First thanks, much appreciated! Now when I try it, I see something must be wrong with the divs, because it breaks the UI. I am trying to understand the if part, seems to complicated to me. You open the div class=row before all of them and where does it close? How is the loop going to display each 4 results in a new div class=row, that I can not understand. Some div must not be closed I think...

Comment: shouldn't it be if($i %4 == 0) instead of if($i %4 != 0)

Comment: @Standej now when I try, it puts the 1st, 2nd, 3rd results each in different div class=row and the 4th and 5th together in another div class=row

Comment: @Neo Thanks true fixed if($i %4 == 0)

Comment: @TsvetilinBoynovski pls check edit i do mistake with if This is correct if($i %4 == 0)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php

...

$temp_count = 0;

echo "<div class='row'>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_result)){

    if($temp_count  == 4){
        echo "</div><div class='row'>";
        $a = 0;
    }

    echo {YOUR_DATA};
    $temp_count++;


}

echo "</div>";

?>
```